# Ruby On Rails Association error missing an [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner with Ruby On Rails and i have run into in error while trying to make association between three models: TipList, Category, Tip. When a user makes a new tip_list they are taken to the view page for the categories. Then once they make a new category for that tip_list it takes the user back to the view page for all the categories and the browser is returning an error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories",     :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :tip_list_id=># Category id: 4, name: "stuff",     created_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12", updated_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12",     tip_list_id: 4 id: 4, name: "stuff",     created_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12", updated_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12",     tip_list_id: 4>} missing required keys: [:id]

My Models looks like:

```
class TipList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tips, through: :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tip_list
  has_many :tips, dependent: :destroy
end

class Tip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :tip_list
end
```

My category Controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :set_tip_list
  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def index
    @categories = @tip_list.categories.all
  end


  def show
    @category = @tip_list.categories.find(params[:category_id])
  end

  def new
    @category = @tip_list.categories.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @category = @tip_list.categories.new(category_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to tip_list_categories_path(@tip_list.id, @category) , notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end


  def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @category.update(category_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end

  def destroy
@category.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
  end

  private

    def set_category
  @category = @tip_list.category.find(category_params)
end

    def set_tip_list
  @tip_list = TipList.find(params[:tip_list_id])
end


    def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:id,:name)
end
end
```

The index page for the index of the categories looks like

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<h1>Listing Categories for Tip List: <%= @tip_list.name %></h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', tip_list_category_path(category) %>      </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: {     confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Category', new_tip_list_category_path %>
```

I must be missing something, my database table for categories has a tip_list_id, so i don't know where I went wrong. If you could help that would be great!

Comment: You'll do well for yourself in the long run if you learn to look closely at the super helpful error rails gives you. Read `{:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :tip_list_id=># Category id: 4, name: "stuff", created_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12", updated_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12", tip_list_id: 4 id: 4, name: "stuff", created_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12", updated_at: "2015-02-13 23:26:12", tip_list_id: 4>}` closely. See how `:id` is `nil` and `:tip_list_id` has a `Category` object, instead of just an integer? Can you see why that is happening?

Comment: I already new that the :tip_list_id was returning an object and not an integer. When i added the :tip_list_id column to the Category table I made sure to make it an integer and i don't know why it's returning that value.

Comment: Okay, look at this: `<%= link_to 'Show', tip_list_category_path(category) %>`. I agree that this should just work, but it doesn't. Try `<%= link_to 'Show', tip_list_category_path(category.trip, category) %>`. You need to tell it the trip and category. Then, you'll get a new error in your `show` action, because `category_id` is not one of the params, you want just `id`.